# Angular highcharts scroll not working while drag over the chart on mobile

Tags: html, angular, typescript, highcharts, angular8

I am using basic line Highcharts on my Angular 8 project. While I'm trying to use the system on the iPhone I can't scroll the page over the area where a chart is lying. Chart is preventing page scrolling from working. This is very annoying for instance when a chart is covering the whole screen, as there's no way to scroll the page in this case.

I am adding a code of my TS function

```js
chartOptions = {

        title: {
            text: 'Your Net Worth'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Money in GBP'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                label: {
                    connectorAllowed: false
                },
                pointStart: 2020
            }
        },
    
        series: [
            {
                name: 'Net Worth',
                color: '#00b300',
                data: [latest_networth_for_chart]
            }
            , {
                name: 'Age group (domestic) (coming soon)',
                color: '#ff0000',
                data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                visible: false
            }, {
                name: 'Age group (expats) (coming soon)',
                color: '#0000b3',
                data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                visible: false
            },
            {
                name: 'Others in your industry (coming soon)',
                color: '#0000b3',
                data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                visible: false
            },
            {
                name: 'Peer group (coming soon)',
                color: '#0000b3',
                data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                visible: false
            },
            {
                name: 'Global average (coming soon)',
                color: '#0000b3',
                data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                visible: false
            },
            {
                name: 'This time last year (coming soon)',
                color: '#0000b3',
                data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                visible: false
            },
        ],
    
        responsive: {
            rules: [{
                condition: {
                    maxWidth: 540
                },
                chartOptions: {
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'horizontal',
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
  }
```

Am I did anything wring on my code?
Regarts, Faz.

Comment: Try to set `tooltip.followTouchMove` to false. API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.followTouchMove let me know if this help

Comment: tooltip: {
          followTouchMove: false,
}

I have tried but not working